# Example of <iframe src= "view-source:http://www.abc.com"></iframe>?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Any working example of

`<iframe src= "view-source:http://www.abc.com"></iframe>`

What would be the main use-case of view-source & is there any site that is using or taking advantage of view-source functionality?

Comment: Erm what? You want to display the source of a html/xml/php/etc file inside of an iframe? Use it to display the source code when you need it, e.g. show someone your page/plugin/snippet's code. Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: I think the actual question is "what is the [`view-source` URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View-source_URI_scheme) good for?". Given the fact that this scheme is officially registered at IANA, this is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 1):

`view-source:` is not the same in all browsers.  I think only Chrome uses that.

You can use a proxy to do this.  On your server, make a script that gets the website and then outputs it as text.

PHP Example:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Then you can do:

```
<iframe src="http://mysite.com/path/to/proxy.php?url=http://www.abc.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Unfortunately IE before IE9 thinks it knows better than you what you want, and content sniffs documents sent as `text/plain`. If it sees what it thinks is HTML, it renders it as HTML, not as plain text.

Comment: Browser Support is pretty decent: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View-source_URI_scheme#Browser_Support